# How to determine max size of DecimalFormat before it's shown with exponent?

Tags: java, android, numbers, decimal

I have number displayed in EditText that can go up to 20 character + 4 decimal before it's too long.  I would like to have number that are longer than that displayed with de exposant at the end so it's not truncated.

ex: 123456789 will show as is
123456789123456789123456 is too long and will be displayed as 1.123456789E8 (just an example !)

I have tested this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(20);
```

But after 20char, the numbers are just not displayed correctly.  ex: 123456789123456789123456 became 56789123456789123456 (trunked 4 first digit.)

Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

The [Decimal Formater java doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) descibe how to handle the Exponent.

> Scientific Notation
>
> Numbers in scientific notation are
>   expressed as the product of a mantissa
>   and a power of ten, for example, 1234
>   can be expressed as 1.234 x 10^3. The
>   mantissa is often in the range 1.0 <=
>   x < 10.0, but it need not be.
>   DecimalFormat can be instructed to
>   format and parse scientific notation
>   only via a pattern; there is currently
>   no factory method that creates a
>   scientific notation format. In a
>   pattern, the exponent character
>   immediately followed by one or more
>   digit characters indicates scientific
>   notation. Example: "0.###E0" formats
>   the number 1234 as "1.234E3".
>   ...

The more difficult part is how to switch betwenn normal and Scientific Notation.
I have done this by embedding two decimal formater in an choide formatter within an Messageformater:

```
MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat(
"{0,choice,0#{0,number,'#,##0.####'}|99999<{0,number,'000000.####E0'}}",
                Locale.ENGLISH);
```

*(This excample is with only 6 decimal places, but you can change it.)*

The usage of an message format is a bit different to an decimal formater, because the format metthod expect an array of objects.

```
System.out.println(format.format(new Object[] { 123 }));
```

What it prints for (1, 12, 123, ...) is:

```
1
1.1
12
123
1,234
12,345
123456E0
123456.7E1
123456.78E2
123456.789E3
123456.789E4
123456.789E5
123456.789E6
```

*You need to tune the pattern a bit that it matches your 20 diget requirement, but the way should be clear.*

Even if I have showed that it worked, I would recommend to implement your own Formater which uses 2 decimal formater and an if condition.

Answer (score 0):

`E` is used to Format the number in Exponential Notation.  Is that what you're looking for?

```
new DecimalFormat("####E0")
```

I'm not sure what an exposant is.

Comment: If the number is greater than or equal to 10000000000000000000, use this format, else use some other format.  If you're reading a String, this is just as easy and you can use the length.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Exposant is Exponent in french !

This work, but I would like to have exponential format only when number is longer than 20 characters.  And if it's 20 or less character, I want to have the 4 decimals if there's any...

Comment: It would be better to edit your question instead of adding this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ralph !  Exactly what I was loking for !

Here what I have done:

```
MessageFormat df = new MessageFormat("{0,choice,0#{0,number,'#.####'}|9999999999999999999<{0,number,'#.######E0'}}",
Locale.ENGLISH);
EditText2.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(new Object[] { Float.valueOf(EditText1.getText().toString()) * 1024})));
```